# Turn Google Cardboard VR/stereo on and off in unity2017.3 using GoogleVR v1.120.0 with headtracking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stereo-3d, google-vr

Does anyone know how to turn stereo rendering mode on and off (preferably while keeping headtracking active) for a google cardboard unity app ? This was possible in unity 5.6 and older GoogleVR sdk's, but not anymore it seems.

The google VR documentation is way out of date and examples I've found of switching between stereo  and normal rendering are also out of date.

I've been trying but can't get it to work. And please only tested solutions. I've seen way too many 'this should work' solutions that simply don't work.

regards,